# Finding a range of numbers of a file in another file using awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have lots of files like this:

```
3 
10 
23
.
.
.
720
810
980
```

And a much bigger file like this:

```
2 0.004
4 0.003
6 0.034
. 
.
.
996 0.01
998 0.02
1000 0.23
```

What I want to do is find in which range of the second file my first file falls  and then estimate the mean of the values in the 2nd column of that range.

Thanks in advance.

NOTE

The numbers in the files do not necessarily follow an easy pattern like 2,4,6...

Comment: This is a broad problem. You should focus it by posting some desired output, what did you do so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your smaller files are sorted you can pull out the first row and the last row to get the min and max. Then you just need go through the bigfile with an awk script to compute the mean.

So for each smallfile `small` you would run the script

```
awk -v start=$(head -n 1 small) -v end=$(tail -n 1 small) -f script bigfile
```

Where `script` can be something simple like

```
BEGIN {
    sum = 0;
    count = 0;
    range_start = -1;
    range_end = -1;
}
{
    irow = int($1)
    ival = $2 + 0.0
    if (irow >= start && end >= irow) {
            if (range_start == -1) {
                range_start = NR;
            }
            sum = sum + ival;
            count++;
        }
    else if (irow > end) {
            if (range_end == -1) {
                range_end = NR - 1;
            }
        }
}
END {
    print "start =", range_start, "end =", range_end, "mean =", sum / count
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below:

```
for r in *;  do
    awk -v r=$r -F' ' \
    'NR==1{b=$2;v=$4;next}{if(r >= b && r <= $2){m=(v+$4)/2; print m; exit}; b=$2;v=$4}' bigfile.txt
done
```

**Explanation:**

First pass it saves column 2 & 4 into temp variables. For all other passes it checks if filename r is between the begin range (previous coluimn 2) and end range (current column 2).
It then works out the mean and prints the result.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the reply, but I am not getting any output using that script.

Comment: I misread your question, my example will look for filenames r and then look in which range they fit in your bigger file.