# Syntax error in awk only when adding a for loop

Tags: bash, shell, syntax, awk

This is my script:

```
for i in *.locs 

do

awk -v start=$(head -n 1 ${i}) -v end=$(tail -n 1 ${i})

BEGIN {

    sum = 0;
    count = 0;
    range_start = -1;
    range_end = -1;
}
{
    irow = int($1)
    ival = $2 + 0.0
    if (irow >= start && end >= irow) {
            if (range_start == -1) {
                range_start = NR;
            }
            sum = sum + ival;
            count++;
        }
    else if (irow > end) {
            if (range_end == -1) {
                range_end = NR - 1;
            }
        }
}
END {

    echo "${i}"
    print "start =", range_start, "end =", range_end, "mean =", sum / count
}

done
```

Which gives me this error:

line 15: syntax error near unexpected token `}'

line 15: `}'

But when I first use the awk to generate the variables start and end followed by -f myscript.sh file

I don't get an error:

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What [cyon replied](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22146664/1983854) to your previous question is an `awk` script you have to store separately  as `script.awk`, for example, and call with `awk ... -f script.awk`.

Comment: But because I had so many files and wanted to add that echo "${i}" before printing the result so I could know the result for each file

Comment: `awk` is not `shell`. `echo "${i}"` is a `shell` command. You cannot call `echo` from `awk`, just like you couldn't call it from `C`, etc. It's not clear what you're trying to do which probably means your approach is wrong - if you tell us what you're trying to do and post some small sample input and expected output, we could help.

Comment: Thank you for that Ed Morton. Here is a previous post where I got this script (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22145261/finding-a-range-of-numbers-of-a-file-in-another-file-using-awk) so you can see my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to either quote the entire `awk` script, or escape the dollar signs so that the shell does not expand them as positional parameters before `awk` is called. (Adding single quotes takes care of the other problem, which is that without a line continuation character, the `awk` command itself ends at the end of the line and the rest of the script is parsed as incorrect `bash` code):

```
awk -v start=$(head -n 1 ${i}) -v end=$(tail -n 1 ${i}) '

BEGIN {
...
'
```

Comment: I added the commas but I am still getting an error. I put the second comma in the line before the done

Comment: @JM88 Those are not commas, they are single quote characters.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant single quotes. When I used single quotes I got an error.

Comment: @JM88 my crystal ball says it's probably related to the `echo "${i}"` shell command in your END section. You really need to just update your question to tell us what you're trying to do so we can help you do it right.

Comment: I created this new post, explaining it again. I hope you can understand my problem now. Thanks in advance. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22152486/adding-a-loop-in-awk

Answer (score 0):

Characters within your awk program are being interpreted by the shell. You can pass your program as a command-line argument to awk, but it must be enclosed in 'single-quotes' to prevent the shell from interpreting it.

Comment: Where exactly do I need to put the quotes?